# How to make text roll over into another textbox? Visual Basic

Tags: textbox, transfer

So, I want to make it so that, when the user pastes something into a textbox, once it pastes the first 24 characters into that textbox, it will send the rest to a richtextbox.

I've tried splitting, joining, with no luck. I don't know what else I can do. Any ideas?

I've tried:

`If TextBox1.Text > TextBox1.MaxLength Then
            RichTextBox4.Text = TextBox1.Text
        End If`

And some other weird things that didn't work out. I would appreciate some help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use Substring....

```
Dim input = textbox1.text

Dim substring As String = input .Substring(0, 24)

richtextbox4.text = substring
```

http://www.dotnetperls.com/substring-vbnet

Comment: Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged